# Finding the index of a multidimensional array?

Tags: java

What would be the last valid index for this array?

```
double[][] array = new double[11][17];
```

Comment: And you what do you think?

Comment: There are 2 separate indices; which do you mean?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: 17th element of each of the 11 arrays...

Comment: This was a quiz question and i was just confused because it was multidimensional. I know that the last index of the row is 10 and 16 for the column i just wasn't sure if you put it like 10 and 16 or if i was supposed to combine them or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `[10][16]`, let's see how in code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] array = new double[11][17];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("[%d][%d]%n", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

And the last line of output is

```
[10][16]
```

**Or**, you could remember that array indexes start at `0` and the last element of an array is at the length of the array - 1.